# Allocation overhead of AnyVal classes

Tags: scala

1. It is said that classes that extends `AnyVal` can be mixed in only
   with **universal** traits, but it is also said that such usage *incur the overhead of allocation*, the primary goal of *value* classes to fight with. So what is a benefit of mixing in traits into *value* classes if we get allocation overhead anyway.
2. *...may not define a equals or hashCode method.* In [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) article case classes are successfully used extending `AnyVal`. But how about generated `equals` and `hashCode` of case classes?. AlsoI've tried to use case classes that extends `AnyVal` and compiler doesn't complain. Do we have instantiation overhead in such case?

Comment: I don't think you read the whole http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html article.

Comment: I don't think you're right. Point me what is explained in that doc that I ask question about

Comment: "When Allocation Is Necessary" downwards.